# Postgresql Import File Error : date/time field value out of range: "00000000"

Tags: postgresql, date, postgresql-12

I'm trying to import .txt file which contains pipe(|) separated data and datetime value as  "00000000" for null value. While importing this file I'm getting below error.

```
SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "00000000"
Where: COPY drugdata, line 1, column desdtec: "00000000"
```

**Query which I'm trying to execute:**

```
copy drugdata  from '/home/manishl/drugdbfile/drugdata.txt' with delimiter as '|';
```

**Sample Data for drugdata.txt**

```
00002091155|TEMPO SMART BUTTON|00000000|00000000
00002094755|TEMPO REFILL KIT|00000000|00000000
```

**drugdata table schema :**

```
CREATE TABLE public.drugdata(
ndc varchar(11) NOT NULL,
desc varchar(1000) NULL,
startdate date NULL,
expirydate date NULL);
```

Is there any way to replace datetime value "00000000" to null?

Comment: If you have no other "null" values, you can try `with (delimiter '|', NULL '00000000')`

Comment: thanks for the answer, can we handle multiple null values? another table there is blank space for the date column and it should consider as null

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other strings that represent NULL, you can use that one with the COPY command:

```
copy drugdata  
  from '/home/manishl/drugdbfile/drugdata.txt' 
  with (delimiter '|', null '00000000');
```

Comment: can we handle multiple null values? another table there is blank space for the date column and it should be consider as null

Comment: Well, an import for "another" table would use a different COPY. If you want to use `'00000000'` **and** and an empty string as NULL, you could try to use `FORCE_NULL` for those columns where an empty string should be NULL

Comment: can you please update your answer to handle '00000000' and and an empty string as NULL